# get value of submit in Text field when form is post in PHP

Tags: php, forms, textbox

I need the value of submit button when form is posted in existing text field. and below is the code.

I trying out but it is creating a new text field.

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['hello'];
//below here i am trying out something but not getting in exiting textfield.
//i need the value of submit button ie some value in exiting textfield ie text1
echo "<input type='text' name='text1' value='$var1'>";

?>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hello" value="some value">
<input type="text" name="text1" value="dskfjls">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would create a new text field, because that's what you're `echo` is doing.

Just change it do:

```
<?php
$submitbutton = $_POST['hello'];
$textbox = $_POST['text1'];
//below here i am trying out something but not getting in exiting textfield.
//i need the value of submit button ie some value in exiting textfield ie text1
echo $submitbutton;
echo $textbox;

?>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hello" value="some value">
<input type="text" name="text1" value="dskfjls">
</form>
```

---

Edit in reply to comment

Use this:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hello" value="some value">
<input type="text" name="text1" value="<?php (isset($_POST['hello'])?$_POST['hello']:null); ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: I want the value of submit button to be displayed on textfield

Comment: the above code is not working and even i got the concept to display the value and even i tried this one its working.`<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hello" value="some value">
<input type="text" name="text1" value="

<?php
if($_POST['hello'])
{echo $_POST['hello'];}

?>">
</form>`